# Why did Christian Dassault attack Bourne?

Tags: plot-explanation, jason-bourne

In *Jason Bourne* (2016), Christian Dassault is the leader of a group of privacy activists. He wants to expose systems like top-secret black ops program of the Central Intelligence Agency which want to control public behavior. While Bourne going through the old Treadstone files to retrace his
history suddenly Dassault attacks Bourne. Why did he attack him?

Comment: thought maybe Bourne will be a roadblock to achieve what he wanted?

Comment: Maybe because he thought that Jason helped CIA to track him?